# 2 Tables sharing a relation table in Entity Framework 4.1 (Code-First) mapping advice?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to create a mapping from 2 tables and have them share a link table? I am not sure if this would work, but there may be a better way to do this and wanted to get some advice. Here is my idea for the mappings:

```
//For Attachments
HasOptional(a => a.Subscription).WithMany().Map(m => {m.MapLeftKey("SubscriptionID"); m.MapRightKey("EntityId"); m.ToTable("Subscriptions);});

//For Submittals
HasOptional(s => s.Subscription).WithMany().Map(m => {m.MapLeftKey("SubscriptionID"); m.MapRightKey("EntityId"); m.ToTable("Subscriptions);});
```

Will this create the one link table for both entities to share? Is this a good approach or should I have a FKs for each entity in a subscription table?

Update: I don't think those mappings will work since it is a many-to-one? This may be more appropriate:

```
HasOptional(s => s.Subscription).WithMany().Map(m => {m.MapKey("EntityId"); m.ToTable("Subscriptions");});
```

[image: Model Example]

Comment: Can you specify what is the relationship between Attachment and Subscriptions, Submittal and Subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about this some more, this is not how it works. I ended up just having the FKs for all types in the Subscriptions class. works just like I need.